# On a V6 engine is it OK to replace one head and not the other?

Tags: power, damage, cylinder-head, rebuild

Situation is the cylinder head of a Mitsubishi 3.0 liter V6 engine was damaged after sucking a washer into the intake manifold.

Question: is it OK to just replace the one damaged head or do both heads need to be replaced?

My concern is an unbalance in power between the two banks - can this cause undue stress on pistons or connecting rods?

Comment: The cylinder head is just a (fancy-shaped and rather expensive) tin can. Unless you replace it with a different design of head (e.g. the engine was already customized in some way and you can't be sure of getting an exact replacement) there's no reason to be worried IMO. Of course if you also have to replace the camshaft(s), valves and springs, etc, that would be a very different situation!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the other head is fine then don’t worry.

The pistons are not exactly the same mass, neither are the connecting rods etc so go for it.

The workshop foreman blueprinted (and exceeded) his engine with stunning results but the hours of work....